# Android Animation leaving images outside parent view

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-gridlayout

I have a basic android game similar to 2048. All that's important to the problem is images move around a grid of 4x4. When they move, I animate the move. On some devices the animation spills over past it's cell and does not clean up - it leaves remnants of the image outside the cell. I can't find a fix, please help or offer some advice on a better way to do it :(

- I have a grid layout of 4x4 - 16 squares
- In each square is a relative layout.
- In the relative layout I put the Images

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMon00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_margin="1dp"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:clipChildren="false"
      >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageMon00"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/square_size"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/square_size"
          android:layout_margin="1dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:contentDescription="@string/ig00"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

My animation moves to like images together, produces a 'squash' and then replaces them with a new image

```
//Move the Image
TranslateAnimation move = new TranslateAnimation(fromLoc[0]-toLoc[0],0,fromLoc[1]-toLoc[1],0);
move.setDuration(durationSlide);
move.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
tmpImage.startAnimation(move);
move.setAnimationListener(new IVAnimationListener(getApplicationContext(),toRL,tmpImage,toImage,mon) {                  
    @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //When the move is finished do the squash animation ontop and put the new image below
        int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(monImagePrefix+String.valueOf(monTo.level), "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageTo.setImageResource(imgID);
        Animation popin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.popin);
                            popin.setDuration(durationUpgrade);
        imageTo.startAnimation(popin);      
        imageFrom.setImageResource(R.drawable.splat);
        imageFrom.bringToFront();
        Animation splat = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.squash);
            //When it's all done get rid of the 'squash'
            imageFrom.startAnimation(splat);
            splat.setAnimationListener(new IVAnimationListener(getApplicationContext(),layout,imageFrom,imageTo,monTo) {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    layout.removeView(imageFrom);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and the popin Animation

```
 <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="200"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:startOffset="200"
    >
</scale>
```

and the Squash Animation

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.1"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.1"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:duration="100"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:startOffset="0"
    >
</scale>

<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.5"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="0"
    android:duration="200"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:startOffset="100"
    >
</scale>
```

This works fine. But one some devices leaves a image behind outside of the effected grid cell. A picture show it better:

[image: ScreenShot]

Or it's still broken in my release version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h17.monstermash

Comment: I would set the listener before starting the animation. Not sure if that has an effect though.

Comment: Probably not the issue. The other thing I'd suggest as a quick fix is to also invalidate the whole grid to force redraw.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that ago. It's still bug me resolving the problem without knowing the problem but I can live with that.